# PHP MySQL pagination script download

Tags: php, pagination

I am new to PHP programming, so I want to learn PHP pagination and how actually it works. I want to download ready script that help me to learn pagination.

Can anyone give me site URL which provides a free pagination script.

Answer (score 5):

Following all links contain demo with example code

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

http://www.techumber.com/2012/08/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql.html

http://papermashup.com/easy-php-pagination/

http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=289

**Php Jquery Mysql pagination**

http://zeeshanakhter.com/2013/08/05/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php/

**Ajax Jquery pagination's**

http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/04/best-ajax-jquery-pagination-plugin-tutorial-with-example-demo/

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?v9el3pPQ

http://www.vasplus.info/tutorial.php?id=108&topic=Pagination%20System%20using%20Ajax,%20Jquery%20and%20PHP#.UlK4G9KBlq8

Answer (score 3):

check this [PHP pagination](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/)

pagination with simple code

```
$pages = new Paginator;  
$pages->items_total = $num_rows[0];  
$pages->mid_range = 9;  
$pages->paginate();  
echo $pages->display_pages();
```